# Scroll bar issue with jQuery modal dialog using iFrame

Tags: css, jquery-ui, jquery-ui-dialog

I created a modal dialog with help of jQueryUI. Since i want to load the other page(child.html) i used iFrame here. Everything works fine.

But the issue is, it shows a scroll bar on modal dialog page as well. I tried to remove inner scroll bar by changing few CSS properties, No Use. I am struggling with this UI issue for past 10 days.

Please look at my page here.

http://sharanvijay.com/demo/Modal/html/parent.html

Here is screenshot

[image]

**Note:** Child and parent both pages uses same CSS file.

For showing model i referred

[How to display an IFRAME inside a jQuery UI dialog](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5660263/how-to-display-an-iframe-inside-a-modal-dialog-using-jquery-ui-dialog)

Can some one figure out with some fiddling tool like fire fox or any and suggest me what should i do?

Answer (score 1):

Look in "/Modal/css/jquery-ui.css":

```
.ui-dialog .ui-dialog-content {
position: relative;
border: 0;
padding: .5em 1em;
background: none;
overflow: auto;
zoom: 1;
```

The problem goes away when I unticked `overflow: auto;` from the developer mode in Chrome, so maybe you can delete it if neccessary.

Comment: Thanks, looks good. But i cant able to see my buttons at the bottom when i remove overflow:auto. Can you help my page look better aligned!

Comment: Look at: `<div class="ui-dialog ui-widget ui-widget-content ui-corner-all ui-draggable ui-resizable" style="outline: 0px; z-index: 1002; position: absolute; height: auto; width: 850px; top: 8px; left: 74px; display: block;" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="ui-id-2">`. You might want to replace that `height: auto;` with a proper value like `height: 640px;`, for example. Try it and play with that "height" property and set a value where you feel it looks the way you're looking for.