# Any jQuery convention for calling function in parent document from iFrame document?

Tags: javascript, jquery, iframe, conventions

Is there any convention for functions written in jQuery that are to be called from a child document (i.e. inside an `<iframe>`) to the parent document?

Following on from [my question yesterday](https://stackoverflow.com/q/21413455/930393), regarding the use of an `iFrame` in a jQuery UI `.dialog`... I need the page inside the `iframe` to alter the size of the dialog at a particular time.

I already have this working, with the following code in the child document...

```
window.parent.$("#myDiv").dialog("option", "height", 180).dialog("option", "width", 300);
```

However, I think it would be cleaner and easier to understand if the code (which is much more complex than just that line) was included with the original `.dialog` code in the parent document.

This could obviously be done simply having the following in the parent document...

```
function resizeDialog() {
  $("#myDiv").dialog("option", "height", 180).dialog("option", "width", 300);
}
```

... and the following in the child document

```
window.parent.resizeDialog();
```

However, I want to know if there is any convention for including the resizeDialog function as part of the `$("#myDiv")` so that it be called with something like...

```
$window.parent.$("#myDiv").resize();
```

---

**Update**

I guess the question I'm trying to ask is this:

Is it considered unacceptable to have a function like this when using jQuery...

```
function resizeDialog() {
  $("#myDiv").dialog("option", "height", 180).dialog("option", "width", 300);
}
```

If so, then what is the format for having a jQuery function that can be called from outside of the current document?

Answer (score 0):

You need to create a custom jQuery plugin for that

```
    (function ($) {
    // plugin definition
    $.fn.resizeDialog = function () {

       this.dialog("option", "height", 180).dialog("option", "width", 300);
       }
   })(jQuery);
```

If the above code gives you some error, you can check the exact syntax [here](http://learn.jquery.com/plugins/basic-plugin-creation/)

**Update:**
If you want to apply your method to jQuery dialogs only then you can write a function in the `$.widget( "ui.dialog", { });` function.
eg. syntax:

```
_resizeDialog : function() {// your code here}
```

Comment: Thanks Rajesh. Does that mean that the `.resizeDialog` would become available on ALL objects within jQuery?  I will add an extra part to my question to see if it makes more sense

Comment: Yes that will be available to all objects.

Comment: In that case, it's not what I'm looking for.. but thanks anyway

Comment: Ok I am confused if you want to use your method like `$("#myDiv").resizeDialog();' then this method have to be a jQuery method that acts on jQuery objects '$("#myDiv")` in your case. and if you want to use this method only for specific elements you have to define its scope.

Comment: Fair enough - then how do I define its scope?