# Iframe content not loaded in JQuery Dialog

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui, iframe, jquery-ui-dialog

i have a page where i will create a iframe dynamically and append that to a div.
That div will be attached to a jquery dialog.

```
<div id="diviframe"></div>
<script>
var iFrame = $('<iframe id="thepage" width="450" height="400"></iframe>').appendTo("#diviframe");
    var iFrameDoc = iFrame[0].contentDocument || iFrame[0].contentWindow.document;
    iFrameDoc.write('<p>Some useful html</p>');
    iFrameDoc.write('<p>Some useful stuff</p>');   
    iFrameDoc.close();


    $("#diviframe").dialog({

        autoOpen: false,
        modal: true,
        height: 500,
        width:500,
        open: function(ev, ui) {

    }

    });

$("#diviframe").dialog('open');
```

The contents of iframe is not written when its opened in jquery dialog.
can anyone suggest a workaround for this?

***Update:***

```
 function test() {
        var iFrame = $('<iframe id="thepage" width="500" height="500" src="http://stackoverflow.com"></iframe>').appendTo("#diviframe");
        var parent = "divparent";
        var iFrameDoc = iFrame[0].contentDocument || iFrame[0].contentWindow.document;
        iFrameDoc.write('<p>Some useful html</p>');
        iFrameDoc.write('<p>Some useful stuff</p>');
        iFrameDoc.close();      
        return iFrame;
    }






    var $dialog; //Must be at the global scope
    function dialog() {      
        alert(1);
        $.get(test, {}, function(html) {
            $dialog.html(html);
            $dialog.dialog("open");
        });
    }

    $(function() {
        //Initialize (without showing it)
        var $dialog = $('<div id="dialog" title=""></div>').dialog({
            autoOpen: false,
            modal: true
        });
    });
    dialog();
```

I tried to call a function dynamically after the jquery dialog loads but its showing some errors. How to load a function from jquery dialog?

Answer (score 0):

I don't think you need to use an iframe for what you're doing, unless you've stripped out some vital detail before posting your question.

You can append your content directly to #diviframe, and it'll display just fine.

```
$("#diviframe").append("<p>Some useful html</p>");
$("#diviframe").append("<p>Some useful stuff</p>");
```

I wonder - are you trying to make a scrollable panel inside the dialog? If so, you can set the CSS of a div to achieve what you need:

```
.myScrollableBox {
    width: 450px;
    height: 400px;
    overflow: auto;
    border: 1px solid #000;
}
```

You might also want to add some padding to that, so that the text isn't jammed hard against the borders.

Comment: I need to use iframe as the content will load in another domain. i just provide you a sample not the whole code as that will not make sense here.are you able to find out why iframe content not loaded?

Comment: I think the problem is that you're dynamically modifying the document, but the copy jQuery makes for inside the dialog just takes the outer iframe element.

Comment: yes. what you said is right. Its taking the outer iframe which created initially.

Comment: Can you create the iframe with say `src="http://stackoverflow.com"` as an attribute, and see if it embeds in the dialog?

Comment: Ah, ok. Try this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5660263/how-to-display-an-iframe-inside-a-modal-dialog-using-jquery-ui-dialog

Comment: that's fine.  But as per my reuirement, i need to write the contents dynamically. is it possible to set the iframe contents to dialog html?

Comment: If you need to change the content of the iframe after it's loaded, you'll need to modify it after the dialog opens, because that's when the iframe will load its content.

Comment: As you said i tried to call a function from jquery dialog and created Iframe dynamically. But i couldnt call a function from jquery dialog. Can you identify where i made wrong? The question updated.