# Changing Window.open to modal dialog javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, c#-4.0

I am working on some browser neutral issue and I see code is in  `window.open()` for new window, it works in IE-11(but not modal pop-up) and not in any other browsers such as Edge, Safari, Chrome.

the currently the window.open() is not of **Modal** type so is there any way I can change this window to modal and could work in all above mentioned browsers in a easy way ?

here is the code

```
function ShowAbbreviationDefinition_onclick()
    {
        var windowOptions = "toolbar=no,location=no,status=no,menubar=no,scrollbars=no,height=400,width=400,left=300,top=150"
        window.open("../UserControls/Somepage.aspx", "", windowOptions);
    }
```

Thanks.

Comment: Use jquery dialog or anyother modal dialogs.

Comment: what about set `target=_blank` in `window.open()`?

Comment: There are lots of different modal/dialog scripts and plugins readily available all over the web. Did you even try looking?

Answer (score 0):

You can try using jQuery UI dialog. For that you need to add jQuery UI css and js files to your page.

```
<div id="dialog" style="display:none;"></div>

function ShowAbbreviationDefinition_onclick(url){
    $("#dialog").append($("<iframe />").attr("src", "UserControls/Somepage.aspx")).dialog();
}
```

Comment: jQuery doesn't have a dialog, jQueryUI does but also requires including source files which isn't mentioned here

Answer (score 0):

If you want a native ASP.NET component, you can refer to [MSDN blog posts](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/chaitanya_medikonduri/2012/02/10/modal-popup-windows-in-asp-net-web-applications/).

Otherwise, jQueryUI provides an entire framework with a completely client-based modal called [Dialog](https://jqueryui.com/dialog/).

You'll want to understand that an iframe will need to contain the `Somepage.aspx` URI. See this [other answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5660263/how-to-display-an-iframe-inside-a-jquery-ui-dialog).